# Cannot create an instance of ViewModel class (Unable to start activity ComponentInfo)

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I am using MVVM, Retrofit, LiveData in my project but I get this error before that I saw these links

- [Cannot create an instance of custom ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45459917/5528079)
- [Cannot create an instance of class ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44998051/5528079)

### Error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:       
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.orangehat.movieinfo/ir.orangehat.movieinfo.application.home.HomeActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException:

Cannot create an instance of class ir.orangehat.movieinfo.application.home.HomeViewModel
```

### ViewModel

I think the problem is in my constructor

```
public class HomeViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private MovieRepository movieRepository;

public HomeViewModel(@NonNull Application application, Context context, LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner) {
    super(application);
    movieRepository = new MovieRepository(lifecycleOwner, context);
}

LiveData<List<Movie>> getMovies() {
    return movieRepository.getMovies();
}}
```

### Repository

```
public class MovieRepository extends BaseRepository {

private LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner;
private MovieApi movieApi;
private MovieDatabaseHelper movieDatabaseHelper;

public MovieRepository(LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner, Context context) {
    this.lifecycleOwner = lifecycleOwner;
    movieApi = getRetrofitHelper().getService(MovieApi.class);
    movieDatabaseHelper = new MovieDatabaseHelper(context);
}

public LiveData<List<Movie>> getMovies() {
    LiveData<List<Movie>> moviesLiveData = movieApi.getMovieList();
    moviesLiveData.observe(lifecycleOwner, new Observer<List<Movie>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Movie> movieArrayList) {
            movieDatabaseHelper.Save(movieArrayList);
        }
    });

    return movieDatabaseHelper.getAll();
} }
```

### Activity class

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // the error is here
        HomeViewModel homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);

        homeViewModel.getMovies().observe(HomeActivity.this, new Observer<List<Movie>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Movie> movieArrayList) {
                String str = null;
                if (movieArrayList != null) {
                    str = Arrays.toString(movieArrayList.toArray());
                }
                Log.e("movies", str);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Should I use Dagger in my project and custom factory?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation for `AndroidViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel.html):

> Subclasses must have a constructor which accepts Application as the only parameter.

Your constructor does not meet that requirement.

Either:

- Remove the `Context context` and `LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner` constructor parameters from your `HomeViewModel`, or
- Create [a `ViewModelProvider.Factory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.Factory.html) that can build your `HomeViewModel` instances, and use that factory with `ViewModelProviders.of()`

Comment: I am working on it based on your answer @commonsware

Comment: I have using only one constructor but the issue is coming. when i remove constructor and used viewmodel as base class its working fine.

Comment: Not working even if the constructor has single "Application application" as parameter..

Comment: @Himanshu: Yes, it does. See [this sample Java project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v0.8/DiceLight), as well as [this one](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v0.8/SimplePrefs) and [this one](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v0.8/Weather). See also the equivalent Kotlin projects [here](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v0.8/DiceLight), [here](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v0.8/SimplePrefs), and [here](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v0.8/Weather).

Comment: @CommonsWare I understand that your answer is correct.. but there are certain other scenarios when this error is thrown even if your ViewModel class has a public constructor with a single Application class parameter. In my case, it was working in one project but not working in another. Looks like there was some dependency issue. Thasnks for your answer though.

Answer (score 6):

If you are working with Kotlin and you need to inject a dependency inside your ViewModel constructor to work with like a Repository to get data (the same way we use to do with the Presenter layer) you will need to do the following.

Lets say we have a ViewModel that needs a UseCase/Interactor to be injected in the constructor to get data from.

```
class MainViewModel(private val itemList:ItemListUseCase):ViewModel() {
...
}
```

When we try to instantiate this ViewModel in our **Activity/Fragment**, we tend to do this

Fragment example

```
   class MainFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel
    
      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
            mainViewModel = requireActivity().run {
                ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
            }
          ...
        }
}
```

When we try to run our code, it will crash with a `RuntimeException`

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class
> com.gaston.example.viewmodel.MainViewModel ... Caused by:
> java.lang.InstantiationException:
> java.lang.Class<com.gaston.example.viewmodel.MainViewModel>
> has no zero argument constructor

This is because we are not injecting the `ItemListUseCase` when we instantiate our `ViewModel`

The first thing that comes up is to try to inject it directly from the `.get()` method of `ViewModelProvider`

```
ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel(ItemListUseCase()))
```

But if we do this, we will be getting the same error too.

### Solution

What we need to understand is that

```
ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
```

`ViewModelProvider()` is trying to do an instance of the MainViewModel without knowing that it needs a dependency inside its constructor.

To fix this issue, we will need to let `ViewModelProvier()` know about which dependency we want to inject.

To do this, we need to create a class that will ensure that the instance of that ViewModel needs a dependency to be instantiated.

This class is called a Factory ViewModel class, since it will construct our ViewModel with the dependency it needs to work and then it will let the `ViewModelProvier()` know which dependency we need to pass to `.get(MainViewModel::class.java)`

```
class ViewModelFactory(val requestItemData: ItemListUseCase):ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return modelClass.getConstructor(ItemListUseCase::class.java).newInstance(requestItemData)
    }
}
```

Now, we can tell to ViewModelProviers.of() that it needs an instance of `ItemListUseCase::class.java` to instantiate `MainViewModel(ItemListuseCase())`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        mainViewModel = requireActivity().run {
            ViewModelProvider(this,ViewModelFactory(ItemListUseCase())).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        }

    }
```

**Note** that I do not pass any arguments to `.get(MainViewModel::class.java)` because our Factory will take care of injecting those arguments into our constructor.

At the end, if you want to avoid the Factory class, you can always use Dagger to inject your dependencies without worrying about the ViewModel Factory class.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this:

```
private LiveData<Section[]> movies;
```

And then, change this:

```
LiveData<List<Movie>> getMovies() {
    if(movies==null)
        movies= movieRepository.getMovies();
    return movies;
}
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps someone. In my case everything CommonsWare told was right, however, I forgot to inject the AppComponennt.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // this line was missing
        ((BaseApplication) getApplication()).getAppComponent().inject(this); 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    In HomeViewModel class need to extend ViewModel class.


public class MovieListViewModel extends ViewModel {
        private MutableLiveData<MovieModel> data;
        private MovieRepository movieModel;

        public MovieListViewModel() {
            movieModel = new MovieRepository();
        }

        public void init() {
            if (this.data != null) {
                // ViewModel is created per Fragment so
                // we know the userId won't change
                return;
            }
            data = movieModel.getMovies();
        }

        public MutableLiveData<MovieModel> getMovies() {
            return this.data;
        }
    }
```

https://github.com/kamydeep00178/androidMvvm can aslo check full example

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned in other answers, ViewModelProviders cannot inject objects that you require in ViewModel constructor.

If you need to set up ViewModel **quick and ugly** without any factories, then you can use Dagger2 that would create `getYourViewModel()` method in the generated `DaggerActivityComponent`, while putting those objects into your constructor that you made available with @Provides annotation. Then just add this field to your activity:

```
@Inject
lateinit var viewmodel: YourViewModel
```

and inject it in `OnCreate()` and that's it. **NB**: Be careful with this approach with heavy and slow ViewModels.

Answer (score -4):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-in-android), you can do this

```
class MvpApp : Application(){

    companion object {
        lateinit var application: Application
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        application = this
    }
}
```

and then:

```
class ProfileViewModel: AndroidViewModel(MvpApp.application) {}
```